# JAVA - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

Tags: java, methods, static

```
public class lookFor {

    //Tools
    //It returns the position of an element at the ArrayList, if not found returns -1
    public int User(String target, ArrayList<User> users){
        for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){
            if(users.get(i).getUserName().equals(target)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

For some reason, when i try to call "User" [This Error appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyxIb.png)

And asks me to make the "user" method a static method, but i don't know what repercussion will it have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the `User` method in a **static** context (`main` method for the example), you need to **instantiate** the **lookFor** class and call the `User` method on that object :

```
lookFor look = new lookFor(); // Use appropriate constructor
if(look.User(username, users) == -1) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you all! what a noob mistake ^^u

Answer (score 2):

A static method belongs to the class, a non-static method belongs to an instance of the class.
You need to create an instance of the class:

```
 lookFor look = new lookFor();
```

And write like this:

```
 if(look.User(username,users)==-1){....};
```

> Static means there is one for an entire class, whereas if it is non-static there is one for each instance of a class (object). In order to reference a non-static method you need to first create an object, and call it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make an instance of the `lookFor` class in order to call it's non-static methods.

```
lookFor lf = new lookFor();
if(lf.User(username,users)==-1) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access USER method within static method then you get this error.

> The only way to call a non-static method from a static method is to
>   have an instance of the class containing the non-static method. By
>   definition, a non-static method is one that is called ON an instance
>   of some class, whereas a static method belongs to the class itself.

For example :

You could create an instance of the class you want to call the method on,

```
new lookFor().USER(target, list);
```